# JSON Copy activity from Azure Table to Data LAke Gen2 failing in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am facing an error when trying to do a JSON copy activity with ‘Source’ as an Azure Table and ‘Sink’ as ADLS Gen 2 Storage.

The error is:

> Operation on target TableToADLSPipeline failed:
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorColumnMappingNotAllowed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
>   mapping is not allowed for copy between 'AzureTableStorage' and
>   'AzureBlobFS(JsonFormatV2)'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

However, when they  save the file in CSV format and it works fine.  Is there some sort of restriction inherent to copying data from Azure Table Storage to Azure Blob Storage in JSON format?  What are other options besides the CSV files for the ADLS Blob (Container) storage for copying data from Azure Data Table?  The client may not want the CSV format.  Is that my only alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repro the issue and I think you have not set the mapping . Setting the mapping is very easy you can do that from the UI .See the screen shot below .
[image]